# How to change the colors based on the select value d3.js v4

Tags: d3.js, treemap

So I have built the treemap based on Mike Bostock's example. url: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/911ad09bdead40ec0061

I want the user to have a color choice. In this example, Mike is using color Magnum and I want to leave it as a default. But I also want to have colors like yellow and green based on user's choice. How would I do that dynamically?

I am using version 4 of d3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured the way if anyone would have the same requirement.

First, I created select options and provided values such as, green and blue
Second, using jquery I change grab the value `$('#colorChoice').change(function())` inside of the function i select all rect by `selectAll('rect')` and provide the style `.style("fill", function(d){})` whatever color you want can be specified inside of the function and return